# Spectrum of C* algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, group-theory, representation-theory

In the spectral theory of bounded operators on a Banach space $X$, the spectrum of a operator has three parts: the point spectrum, the continuous spectrum and the residue spectrum. And note the spectral theorem for a single bounded self-adjoint operator $A$ on a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ can be viewed as an isomorphism of $C^{*}$ algebras $C(\sigma(A))$ and the sub $C^{*}$-algebra generated by $A$ in $\mathscr{L}(\mathscr{H})$.

I am wondering whether there is an analog division for the spectrum of unitary representations of $C^{*}$-algebras into point, continuous and residue spectrum.

My motivation for this problems comes from the Plancherel formula for reductive groups over a local field, namely, the right regular representation $L^{2}(G)$ of Hecke algebra (viewed as a $C^{*}$-algebra), my rough understanding is that for the regular representation $G$ on $L^{2}(G)$, there is a discrete part $L^{2}(G)_{disc}$ and the discrete series representations of $G$ contribute to this part, also there is a continuous part $L^{2}(G)_{cont}$, which should correspond to the parabolic induction of discrete series from smaller Levi subgroups of $G$. I don't quite understand the residue spectrum $L^{2}(G)_{res}$, for some groups $G$ there is no residue spectrum, but I think the residue spectrum and the discrete, continuous spectrum should be disjoint.

Any references or examples are very helpful for me!

Comment: The usual disjoint partition of the spectrum of a linear operator is point(rather than discrete) + residue + continuous. However in the topology of $\mathbb{C}$ the point spectrum is discrete.